# Online Library of Unlabeled Connected Graphs on n Vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Does anyone know of the link to an online library of of unlabeled, connected graphs on n vertices?  I remember looking at such an archive a few years ago while at a Macaulay 2 workshop, but I've been unable to find it (or any other one) since then.

The page I remember seeing only had enumerated unlabeled graphs up to n=11,12, or 13 vertices, and the graph I'm looking for data on is much larger, so links to repositories of larger (special) graphs.

The most specific part of this request:  The graph I'm looking to find a list of edges for is the 1-skeleton of the 600-cell, if anyone happens to just have that information on-hand (or readily available.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this it? It is a searchable database of 
"[Small Simple Graphs:
Connected, undirected, and unlabeled](http://gfredericks.com/sandbox/graphs)."

And an explicit list of the vertices, edges, and faces of the 600-cell can be found
at [Paul Bourke's site](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/platonic4d/).

Comment: That list of vertices and edges was precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Ugh, although in an AWFUL format for what I need it for.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that this is what you remember seeing?
http://wwwteo.informatik.uni-rostock.de/isgci/smallgraphs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the geng tool that comes as part of [nauty here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/), or grab a list of graphs on up to 10 vertices [here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html) (it also has some special classes). It's unlikely you will be able to fit a file of all [50502031367952](http://oeis.org/A000088) graphs on 13 vertices on your computer!

Comment: I certainly didn't want the entire list of them - just was hoping that a website archive of these graphs would have the particular one I was looking for as part of their esoterica!

Comment: Those were the two websites I'd been looking at then and couldn't relocate.  Thanks for the links!